# Can't assign response data to the state data and the response is not empty in React

Tags: json, reactjs, api, django-rest-framework

I'm currently making my first React API application and I can't figure out what the state data is empty even after I assign res.data to it which is not empty.
I also can't figure out how to render all of this inside a div.

Here's what a console.log of res.data returns:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {user: {…}, available_amount: 4324324}
1: {user: {…}, available_amount: 43243243}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

And here's my code:

```
  class App extends Component{
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        let data
        this.state = {
          data: [],
          loaded: false,
          placeholder: "Loading"
        };
      }
    

    async componentDidMount(){
        let data;
        axios
            .get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/',{
                headers:{
                'Authorization': 'Token 8651a2b6c28ecd5cd25c0e67dfd7f3642a3d0029'
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                this.setState(() => {
                    return {
                    data: res,
                    loaded: true
                };
                });
            })
            .then(console.log(this.state.data))

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Appended new state to the previous other than replace, code may be like this.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let data;
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      loaded: false,
      placeholder: "Loading",
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    let data;
    axios
      .get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Token 8651a2b6c28ecd5cd25c0e67dfd7f3642a3d0029",
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
-        this.setState(() => {
-          return {
-            data: res,
-            loaded: true,
-          };
-        });
+        this.setState((prev) => {
+          return {
+            data: prev.data.concat(res),
+            loaded: true,
+          };
+        });
      })
      .then(console.log(this.state.data));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` works asyncrounsly and it's possible that the state is not updated when you call `console.log` in `then`. `setState` actually accepts a callback as its second argument, in which you can check the updated state:

`this.setState(() => {...}, () => { console.log(this.state.data) })`

Btw, considering your new state doesn't rely on the previous state, you can just pass an object to `setState` instead of a function:

```
this.setState(
    {
        data: res,
        ...
    },
    () => {
        console.log(this.state.data)
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...
Change your `setState` to `setState({...})` and
remember the `loading`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const arrayOne = [
  {
    id: 1,
    nome: "Ruan"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    nome: "Paul Symon"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    nome: "Renan Lucas"
  }
];

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      loading: true
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ data: arrayOne, loading: false });
    }, 1000)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.loading ? (
          <h1>Carregando...</h1>
        ) : (
          <div>
            {this.state.data.map((i) => {
              return <h1>{i.nome}</h1>;
            })}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```